# Mixing VB5 and C# in a Windows Form application

Tags: c#, .net, vb5

I'd like to add a window to my application.  Is it possible to "extend" an old vb5 project using C#?

Is it easy to do and maintain and is it a good practice ? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: To add a window to an existing VB5 project is just an example, it could be a feature... but written in C#

Comment: I gave a correct answer. However, I would recommend that you consider upgrading away from this obsolete platform instead of piling more work on top of it. Perhaps a C#/COM approach could be used as a stepping stone to a pure C# application.

Comment: For lots of deep information on .NET <-> COM interop see ".NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide" by Adam Nathan, SAMS. While based on .NET 1.1 (IIRC) not much has changed in this area in later versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is hard as you need to bridge the two worlds.

Both VB5 and C# can create and consume COM object you can use this to call VB5 code from .net or .net code from VB5.

You can also create and use Active X controls in .net, so you can mix VB5 and C# in the same form if you must.

Another option is to have two separate applications that talk to the same database and used COM (or SendMessage) to open forms in each other.

**You need a deep understand of .net to get COM working well, however you are not likely to have that understanding until you have spent some time working in .NET.**

There are also tools on the market that claim to convert VB5 code into VB.NET, however I have not tired any of them.

Answer (score 3):

*edit*

I misread the question initially, thinking you were asking about VB.NET.

The best you can do is expose your C# as a COM object that you call from VB5. You just need to make sure you support `IDispatch`.

Comment: You can not put VB5 projects in a C#/VB.NET solution